# I am getting an error in my pom.xml when trying to build a maven project.I think this is Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Tags: spring-boot, maven

The error is here on this pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.rst.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-demo</artifactId>
<artifactId>springboot-demo</artifactId>
<name>Springboot Demo App</name>
</project>
```

This is the two errors Spring tool suite shows:

1.CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: 
  PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its 
  dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies

2.Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are not inheriting from spring-boot-parent? Apart from that your assumption in the headline is simply wrong)..Which Maven version do you use? and which JDK version?